# Is there a way to determing how many records can a 200 mb SQL Server Db have

Tags: sql-server-2008, shared-hosting

For my product catalog system, i am confused between SQL server database and SQL CE. My hosting provider just gives 200 mb of SQL server, while the disk space provided is 10 GB.

I have four tables with *brands, products, picture and retailers*. The *pciture* table just stores the url and not the binary data. So how many records can this database have. Is the 200 mb space enough for my requirement and is there a way to calculate all this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This query can give you an understanding of what your min, max and average record size for each of your tables is:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS 'Table Name',         
    record_count,
    min_record_size_in_bytes,
    max_record_size_in_bytes,
    avg_record_size_in_bytes
FROM
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED')
```

Take the max size for each row, and multiply it by e.g. 1000 and see how much space 1000 rows each would take up - and go from there.

Comment: ya i will do that after a day or two....so that more people view my question and upvote your answer.....answered question invite very less view....

Comment: following up with this, 423 x 1000 = 423.000. My question would be that numbers is measured in what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is complicated and cannot be very exact. See the following

[Estimating the Size of a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187445.aspx)